# Visual Studio Development Server Directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web

If I make a new web project and run it - it works fine.    If I then change the output directory to something like ....\build - it nicely builds to there, but when you run with the development server, it's still trying to access the  project\bin path, and doesn't work.    Anyone have any idea how to tell it to look in the output directory instead?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Why are you trying to make it not work?

Comment: we use a lot of extra tooling - and it's much easier if you have a directory that's all source and a directory that's all output - putting the output under the source makes a lot of things much more complicated.  With everything else, there's no problem to move it out - but for some reason it doesn't work with web projects

Comment: Are you using web site "projects", or web application projects?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, but you have to be careful and pay attention on the location.
Your question is also not clear enough. Are you planning to have different folders of output folder and dev server folder?

If you really want to separate this, then it should be quite easy.
On your web project properties, set post BUILD event to copy the file to the output directory.
Also don't forget to publish the IIS to the IIS folder of your development server.

[image: Build Event property]

The best practice is not to mix the output directory of your post build event with the folder of your development server as the development server is only for publishing web app.

Comment: I like the suggestion, but want this to work without IIS, with just the built in development server.

Comment: The built in development server is not a real server. It is an IIS Express, built in web server. If you search on MSDN Library, Microsoft will not recommend using IIS Express as your development server. I think you misuse the development server term and assuming the built in web server in Visual Studio is the development server. It is not a real development server.